# Linear Regression: Confidence Interval for X

Tags: r, regression, confidence-interval

So, I'm working with the following data set:

```
0.686   17.6    17.3    16.9    16.2    17.1    18.5    18.7    17.4    18.6    16.8
0.604   24.8    25.9    26.3    24.8    24.8    27.6    28.5    30.5    28.4    27.7
0.508   39.4    37.6    38.1    37.7    36.3    38.7    39.4    38.8    39.2    40.3
0.412   60      58.3    59.6    59.1    56.3    55      52.9    54.1    56.9    56
0.318   87      92.7    90.5    85.8    87.5    88.3    91.6    88.2    88.6    84.7
0.223   128     130     131     129     127     129     132     133     134     133
0.148   199     204     199     207     200     200     205     202     199     199
0.08    298     298     297     288     296     293     301     299     298     293
0.001   423     421     422     428     436     427     426     428     427     429
```

The left column is a given density, and the 10 columns to the right of it are gains for that density.

Based on this data, I found a linear regression model using box cox transformation and a weighted least squares model. The box cox transformation was better so that is the model I'm using.

The transformation suggested was the $\ln$ of $y$ and take $x^{0.89}$. I get the equation $y=-4.48661x+6.10187$. I know how to calculate confidence intervals for $y$ in R, but not sure how to calculate confidence intervals for $x$. I was told the inverse command as well as calibrate might be of help to me. I also have the following equations:

[image]

is there an easy way to compute this using R?